# Применение ButterKnife

Tags: java, android, butterknife

Применение  `ButterKnife.bind(this);`

Есть активити, в ней объявил значения примерно следующим образом:

```
@BindView(R.id.name)
TextView name;
@BindView(R.id.gender)
TextView gender;
```

В методе `onCreate` добавил:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

И ниже в своё методе пробую написать следующим образом:

```
private void someMethod() {
    name.setText(stringFormater.formatString(model.getTitle(), R.string.name));
    gender.setText(stringFormater.formatString(model.getGender().toString(), R.string.score));
}
```

Но получается запуститься только следующим образом:

```
private void someMethod() {
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setText(stringFormater.formatString(model.getTitle(), R.string.name));
    gender= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender);
    gender.setText(stringFormater.formatString(model.getGender().toString(), R.string.score));
}
```

Но так теряется весь смысл применение

Полный код активити:

```
public class TopActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Model model;
@BindView(R.id.name)
TextView name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_story);
    model = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("key");
    populateTextViews();
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

private void populateTextViews() {
    StringFormater stringFormater = new StringFormater(this);
    name.setText(stringFormater.formatString(model.getTitle(), R.string.name));
}
}
```

Comment: Приведённый вами код должен работать. Вы или перепутали ID или не пересобрали проект или вызвали bind до setContentView или ещё куча вариантов которые можно придумывать пока вы не раскроете подробнее что значит "не получается" и не приведёте логи ошибки если она есть

Comment: Покажите код всей активити.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь работать с `TextView` до того, как он будет привязан к активити `ButterKnife`'ом, из-за чего и получаете `NPE`.

Вместо:

```
populateTextViews();
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

должно быть:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
populateTextViews();
```

А лучше вообще прописать биндинг сразу после `setContentView(...)`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_story);
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

И еще, в `build.gradle` касательно `ButterKnife` должно быть две строки:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

---

**UPD**. Если Вы хотите использовать `ButterKnife` в адаптере, то биндить нужно в конструкторе `ViewHolder`:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.name) TextView mName;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
      ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
```

Comment: пробовал писать и выше, выдаёт ошибку. Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.testapp/com.company.testapp.activi‌​ty.TopActivity }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: в этой также + указывает на строчки кода `name.setText(stringFormater.formatString(model.getTitle(), R.string.name));` и `populateTextViews();`

Comment: @Inkognito, Покажите `build.gradle`.

Comment: обновил build.gradle, помогло, использовал только `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'`

Comment: а если мы к примеру в адаптере хотим использовать данный приём, то ButterKnife.bind(this); где нужно вставлять? + вместо this наверное нужно как то по другому использовать.

Comment: @Inkognito, Добавил в ответ.